# Contar cantidad de caracteres que se han introducido en consola

Tags: java, consola, entrada

Cuando ejecuto el programa por consola me gustaría que contara el número de caractes que llevo pulsados, para cuando llegue a 13 haga como si pulso ENTER para introducir el número introducido

El ejemplo del método es éste:

```
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);

    public void escribirCodigo(){
            long codigo = 0;
                System.out.println("Introduce el código de barras.");
            try{             
                    codigo = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());             

                    revisarCodigoBaseDatos(codigo);
                    System.out.println("El valor introducido es: "+codigo);


            } catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error.");
            }
        }
```

El método 'revisarCodigoBaseDatos(codigo)' es donde compruebo si el número introducido se encuentra en la base de datos.
Quiero que cuando compruebe que hay 13 digitos automáticamente en la consola que coja el valor introducido y realice el metodo 'revisarCodigoBaseDatos(codigo)'

Comment: quieres un "evento" de consola para que cuando haya introducido 13 caracteres , haga un "intro" ?

Comment: Si, o alguna otra que me pueda servir para poder comprobar automáticamente el valor introducido por consola

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos formas de hacerlo, la primera y la forma sencilla es que des enter manualmente depues de introducir los 13 digitos.Además es un string puedes usarlo asi. y cuando lo necesites como numero lo parseas

```
public static void main (String args[]){
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
    String codigo= null;
   System.out.println("Introduce el código de barras.");
   codigo=br.readLine();
   escribirCodigo(codigo);
}
public void escribirCodigo(String codigo){
        try{                 
                revisarCodigoBaseDatos(Long.parseLong(codigo));
                System.out.println("El valor introducido es: "+codigo);

        } catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error.");
        }
    }
```

La otra manera es con un evento de teclado que detecte que van 13 teclas presionadas. es dependiendo de las necesidades que tengas.

Recuerda no poner prints en metodos, es una mala practica.

Comment: Que son los prints? gracias por la aportación

Comment: las impresiones en pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Segun entiendo tu deseas tener algo similar a un listener pero en consola, eso no se puede hacer , pero si puedes generar un loop similar a este :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = "";

while (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") == false) {
   line = in.readLine();

   //do something
}

in.close();
```

Comment: Este caso ya lo he visto y no me ha sevido, pero voy a seguir haciendo pruebas a ver si le puedo sacar partido al WHILE. Gracias

Comment: No me sirve parece ser bastante complejo, he leido que se pueden configurar los lectores de condigo de barras para cuando termine de leer el número envie un ENTER,

Comment: si , he utilizado lectores y para configurarlos debes leer un codigo de barras , para que cada vez que se lea un codigo de barras se envie la tecla enter.  Saludos